# Embedding a continuous-time martingale in Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, martingales, embeddings

Using the Skorohod embedding, we can embed any square-integrable discrete time martingale $(M_n)$ into a Brownian motion, obtaining times $(T_n)$ such that $(B(T_n))_{n\ge 0}$ is a version of $(M_n)$. Moreover, if the predictable quartic variation $\langle^4 M \rangle_n := \sum_{k \le n}E[(M_k-M_{k-1})^4 \mid \mathcal{F}_{k-1}]$ exists, it can be used to control the distance of $T(n)$ from the predictable quadratic variation of $(M_n)$. Are similar results known for general continuous-time (but obviously, discontinuous) martingales? I have found results in specific cases, such as stationary or compensated compound Poisson processes, but nothing in full generality. To be clear, in continuous time $\langle^4 M \rangle_t$ would be something like the compensator of the sum of the fourth moments of jumps.